# Node.js - Can't post nested/escaped JSON to body using Fermata REST client

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The problem may be with the actual client, but he's not responding on github, so I'll give this a shot!

I'm trying to post, in the body, nested JSON:

```
{
   "rowkeys":[
      {
         "rowkey":"rk",
         "columns":[
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"{\"date\":\"2011-06-21T00:53:10.309Z\",\"disk0\":{\"kbt\":31.55,\"tps\":6,\"mbs\":0.17},\"cpu\":{\"us\":5,\"sy\":4,\"id\":90},\"load_average\":{\"m1\":0.85,\"m5\":0.86,\"m15\":0.78}}",
               "ttl":10000
            },
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"cv",
               "ttl":10000
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "rowkey":"rk",
         "columns":[
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"fd"
            },
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"cv"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

When I remove the columnvalue's json string, the POST works.  Maybe there's something I'm missing regarding escaping?  I've tried a few built in escape utilities to no avail.

```
var jsonString='the json string above here';

var sys = require('sys'),
      rest = require('fermata'), // https://github.com/andyet/fermata
         stack = require('long-stack-traces');

        var token = ''; // Username
        var accountId = ''; // Password

        var api = rest.api({
             url : 'http://url/v0.1/',
             user : token,
             password : accountId
        });

        var postParams = {
             body: jsonString
        };

        (api(postParams)).post(function (error, result) {
               if (error)
                    sys.puts(error);    

           sys.puts(result);
        });
```

The API I'm posting to can't deserialize this.

```
{
   "rowkeys":[
      {
         "rowkey":"rk",
         "columns":[
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":{
                  "date":"2011-06-21T00:53:10.309Z",
                  "disk0":{
                     "kbt":31.55,
                     "tps":6,
                     "mbs":0.17
                  },
                  "cpu":{
                     "us":5,
                     "sy":4,
                     "id":90
                  },
                  "load_average":{
                     "m1":0.85,
                     "m5":0.86,
                     "m15":0.78
                  }
               },
               "ttl":10000
            },
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"cv",
               "ttl":10000
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "rowkey":"rk",
         "columns":[
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"fd"
            },
            {
               "columnname":"cn",
               "columnvalue":"cv"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: why must the columnvalue have a json string? Can it not just be more json?

Comment: It can't - the json string represents the value of a key/value pair.

Comment: Rude. The json string comes from a file - I'm reading, than posting.  This SHOULD work.

Comment: It's not rude. JSON should not be about re-encoding nested parts as JSON strings. It's either a string, or a JSON object. As you've identified that _that_ is your culprit position, then what happens if you make it a JSON object instead of a JSON string?

Comment: It's not about what JSON is about - it's about what the API that I'm posting to can handle.  I can't nest the JSON like so (see edit), the API can't deserialize it.

Comment: Are you responsible for both the client and the server?

Comment: No, I am not unfortunately - just the client.

Comment: Well there's no reason for this to not work, either as a string or as a JSON object. Any API that can't handle deserializing a JSON object that is _intended_ to work with JSON is a crappy API. It may be trying to deserialize it twice (which would be why it doesn't work). What do you get if you send an equally long string of base64 or hex or something in there?

Comment: Frank, you don't mention how exactly this fails. It looks well-escaped to my eyes, but you can test that by attempting to decode it yourself and check the column value input strings for equality.

Comment: You're right!  I found an issue with the fermata library itself relating to a maximum amount of characters, which I didn't deduce was the problem until today, as it just so happened that my JSON problem happened at the same time the POST became large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dual problems occuring at the same occurred led me to find an issue with the fermata library handling large JSON posts.  The JSON above is just fine!

Comment: Sorry about the whole "not responding" thing - the project is hosted via a team account and I wasn't getting the emails from github! Hope to poke at this soon, and glad to stumble across some more debugging info here.

Comment: No problem!  I figured as much once I checked out website.  I eventually created a simple rest client for myself to debug, probably just an issue in content length that I can't find.  Thanks for responding, though!

Answer (score 0):

I think the real problem here is that you are trying to post data via a URL parameter instead of via the request body.

You are using Fermata like this:

```
path = fermata.api({url:"http://example.com/path");
data = {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"};
path(data).post(callback);
```

What `path(data)` represents is still a URL, with `data` showing up in the query part. So your code is posting to "http://example.com/path/endpoint?key1=value1&key2=value2" with an empty body.

Since your data is large, I'm not surprised if your web server would look at such a long URL and send back a 400 instead. Assuming your API can also handle JSON data in the POST body, a better way to send a large amount of data would be to use Fermata like this instead:

```
path = fermata.api({url:"http://example.com/path");
data = {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"};
path.post(data, callback);
```

This will post your data as a JSON string to "http://example.com/path" and you would be a lot less likely to run into data size problems.

Hope this helps! The "magic" of [Fermata](https://github.com/andyet/fermata) is that unless you pass a callback function, you are getting local URL representations, instead of calling HTTP functions on them.